# Redis - Define maximum log file length

Tags: logging, redis

I am currently configuring my Redis server and I wonder if there is a way to define maximum log file length in the redis.conf ?
I don't see anything about that in the documentation.

Any ideas ? Thanks

Comment: You can log via syslog and set the log size via configuration (most syslog implementations do that). Or use logrotate to rotate the redis log file.

Answer (score 0):

hellvinz was right on track.

I think that `logrotate` is a very appropriate solution for this.

Here's a fairly solid tutorial on `logrotate`: [The Ultimate Logrotate Command Tutorial with 10 Examples](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/07/logrotate-examples/)